# Check for None in the input using a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, is-empty

I am coding a Battleships game in Python and can use some help regarding the while loop to check whether a user has not input any data.

```py
 def getUserInput(self):
        try:
            x_row = input("Please Select the row coorinate (1-8)")
            while x_row not in '12345678':
                print("You are either out of bounds, or don't know what numbers are")
                x_row = input("Please Select the row coorinate (1-8)")

            y_column = input("Please Select the column coordinate (A-H)").upper()
            while y_column not in 'ABCDEFGH':
                print("You are either out of bounds, or don't know what Letters are")
                y_column = input("Please Select the column coordinate (A-H)").upper()
```

It checks for whether the input is in the data range well, but I need it to also check if the user didn't put anything in the input.

I tried an if statement to check whether the user input '' or ' ', as well as equating it to None, but it either just skips over the step to ask for the next input or comes back with a syntax error.

Comment: Change the condition to `while not x_row or x_row not in '12345678'`.  `not x_row` will be true if `x_row` is empty.

Comment: A caveat -- if the user enters something like `12`, that will count as being in the string.  You might want to make the condition `not x_row or x_row not in set('12345678')`, since turning the string into a set (or a list or a tuple) will break it into individual characters.  Another option would be doing `len(x_row) != 1 or x_row not in '12345678'` since the `len` check will force it to be a single-character string, covering both of those edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

This occurance is quite interesting, because as of in python 3.11
the statement `if input("some input here:") == "":\n print("nothing")\n else:\n print("anything")` with an input of nothing returns `nothing` and with every else possible input returns `anything`.
This leaves us with two possibilities:

1. You did make a typo somwhere during testing this, or:
2. You are yousing a python version in wich this does not work for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

You can try using walrus operator (:=) and generator/list/set/tuple such `map(str, range(1,9))` or `list('12345678')` and `list('ABCDEFGH')` when checking for input:

```
while not (x_row := input("Please Select the row coorinate (1-8)")) in map(str, range(1,9)):
    print("You are either out of bounds, or don't know what numbers are")
print(x_row)

while not (y_column := input("Please Select the column coordinate (A-H)").upper()) in list('ABCDEFGH'):
    print("You are either out of bounds, or don't know what Letters are")
print(y_column)
```